# what encoding to use in serviceNow

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, servicenow

I'm having this problem with my CSV Data Source that contains french characters. When I load it on service now those characters are not interpreted correctly (`Installé`becomes `InstallÃ©`).

Any ideas why? my CSV is encoded in UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a "data source" in ServiceNow, and specify the file encoding in that data source record. 
For more info, see the article on Data Sources, [here](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Data_Sources#Encoding&gsc.tab=0).